# Can I extend Enum a la Enum.GetValues()?

Tags: c#

I want to create an extension method that converts any enum into a Json string.

I'd like to be able to attach an extension method to Enum that I can pass an enum-type into, so that it can be called on  `Enum` in the way that you can call `Enum.GetValues(Type enumType)`, so it might look like:

```
Enum.ToJsonString(Type enumType)
```

It seems that this is not possible -- Enum is an abstract class; how could you extend that? -- and that I'll have to create my own static type to implement this.

Can anyone either confirm that I cannot extend Enum this way (and please explain, technically, why), or tell me how I can?

**Clarification (update)**

I know I can do this with my own static type. For example, it would be fairly easy to create `EnumExtensions.ToJsonString(Type enumType)` but I'd rather have the method listed alongside GetValues() et al with VS intellisence auto-complete.

Comment: Do you mean any enum, or any enum *value*? Extension methods always appear as if they were *instance* methods, not static methods. It would be useful to see more about what you'd want your method to do, and how it would be called.

Comment: I mean any enum. I want to be able to convert all the possible values of any enum into a json string with name/hash-code as key/value objects within the json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) defined in C#:

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
>   without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
>   modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of
>   static method, but they are called as if they were *instance* methods on
>   the extended type.

They should be called as they are instance method of type. `Enum` is a type name, and you are trying to write extension which will look like static member of type, which is **not possible**.

What you can do is generic method, which will accept type of enum and convert enum values to JSON:

```
public static string GetEnumJson<T>()
    where T : struct
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (!type.IsEnum)
        throw new NotSupportedException();

    var members = Enum.GetNames(type)
                      .ToDictionary(s => s, s => Enum.Parse(type, s));

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(members);
}
```

And use it with

```
var json = GetEnumJson<DayOfWeek>();
```

Or if you have this method in class JsonHelper then I would go with name GetEnumMembers and
call it this way:

```
var json = JsonHelper.GetEnumMembers<DayOfWeek>();
```

Result:

> {"Sunday":0,"Monday":1,"Tuesday":2,"Wednesday":3,"Thursday":4,"Friday":5,"Saturday":6}

Comment: @James basicly nothing is changed - answer is still *'not possible'* :)

Comment: It seems this is probably the final answer (I'll give it a while). I like the alternative generic method, though I'm dismayed that I cannot specify `where T: Enum` and I must throw an exception if the argument is not an enum ... makes this feel clunky.

Comment: Nice code @SergeyBerezovskiy! :)

Comment: @Faust agree with you - generic type parameter constraints are not very flexible in C# - you cannot add enum constrainet. But I would add contraint to value types at least. Also see question which is ken2k has mentioned

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/ Jon Skeet says it does work :-)

Comment: I think this might not work as expected when an `Enum` has two members with the same value but different names. Trying it now.

Comment: I can confirm, if you try the enum `enum Stupid { A = 1, B = 1 };` you'll get a `ArgumentException` thrown. The problem lies in the `Cast<T>`.

Comment: @FelixK. yep, interesting approach

Comment: @Jodrell you are mythbuster :)

Comment: I've altered my answer to take the best of yours and work around the double value problem.

Comment: @Jodrell sorry, was busy. Now updated code with with simple enum names parsing. It's easy to read and understand, but your appproach has better performance, so +1 from me also :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, my code doesn't work if the enum derives from `ulong` +1 for you.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy you can make it more restrictive: `where T : struct, IConvertible, IComparible, IFormattable`

Answer (score 2):

how about this, You can not do it as an extension because you can't do static extensions in c# (at time of writing.)

Note, this code works if two enum members have the same value (which is unusual but valid.)

```
public static string ToJson<TEnum>()
{
    var enumType = typeof(TEnum);
    if (!enumType.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("enumType");
    }

    var names = Enum.GetNames(enumType);
    var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).OfType<Enum>()
        .Select(e => Convert.ChangeType(e, e.GetTypeCode()));
    var members = names.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v })
        .ToDictionary(p => p.k, p => p.v);

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(members);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add extension to all types and inside check if it enum like this

```
static class EnumEx
{
    public static string ToJsonString(this Type enumType)
    {
        if(!enumType.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("Type should be enum");

        return /* create json string from enum type */
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
enum MyEnum
{
    MyValue1,
    MyValue2,
}

....

var json = typeof(MyEnum).ToJsonString();
```